# ¿Cómo utilizo directivas de preprocesador en una vista Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quiero utilizar una directiva en una vista Razor, estoy usando ASP.MVC 4.0.

```
@{
#if DEBUG
    // Hacer algo en modo depuración.
#else
    // De otra forma hacer lo demás.
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias enviar el flag desde el controller, basicamente en el controler defines

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.IsDebug = false;
        #if DEBUG
            ViewBag.IsDebug = true;
        #endif

        return View();
    }
}
```

entonces en la view podrias definir

```
@if(ViewBag.IsDebug)
{
    // Hacer algo en modo depuración.
}
else
{
    // De otra forma hacer lo demás.
}
```

como veras desde el codigo de la view usas el flag que envias en el ViewBag (puede enviarlo en el model si quieres), de esta forma usas las directivas de C# de forma indirecta

---

Tambien podrias evaluar usar el

[HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/11/using-isdebuggingenabled-in-aspnet.html)

[C# and ASP.NET MVC: Using #if directive in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951128/c-sharp-and-asp-net-mvc-using-if-directive-in-a-view)